# Swift StoryBoard Reference segue to Navigation controller not Root

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, xcode9

Is there a way to use storyboard reference segue to a controller which is the second controller inside a navigation controller?

To be more specific:
I have a cameraViewController in storyboard A.
I would like to create a segue (with a storyboard reference) to storyboard B.
In storyboard B i have a navigation controller with two controller.
The segue should be from storyboard A (cameraViewController) to storyboard B (SecondViewController).
If in the reference I use the StoryBoard reference of the controller the navigation bar is not displayed. And if I use the Storyboard ID of the navigatin controller, well the segue is to root controller.
[image: StoryBoard A]
[image: StoryBoard A]

Thank you.

Comment: You *could* do this from code, not directly via storyboard segues, however... You are showing a "camera view" ... then you want to show "2nd view of a navigation controller". At that point, the user taps the "Back" button in the navigation bar, but instead of going "back to the camera view" you want it to go "*back* to a view the user hasn't seen yet"? Isn't that going to be terribly confusing to the user?

Comment: @DonMag no...i actually would like the user to go back to the cameraView...

Comment: OK - then why not put the "camera view" in a Navigation Controller, and simply push to the view you want to see next... then the Back button takes the user, as expected, back to the camera view.

Comment: @DonMag is a bit complicate storyboard.... that cameraView is part a pagecontroller and that page controller has another navigation controller...

Comment: Sounds like you still need to work out some navigation issues, but... I'm doing a couple screen-caps to give you an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Storyboard, a particular View Controller *can* be linked to more than one navigation structure.

So, you can have `Controller B` as part of more than one Navigation Controller.

In Storyboard "SB_A" create a segue to Storyboard "SB_B", but instead of segueing to the "default" VC in SB_B, segue to the VC identified as "FromSBA" - in this case, "FromSBA" is a 2nd Navigation Controller inside SB_B, whose root VC is `Controller B`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thx! needed to change a bit the code for the segues but now works perfectly... didn't think about adding a new nav controller... and change the back button from popViewController to dismiss... Thank you!